# C2084 Compile-Error (C++)

Tags: c++, declaration, definition, member-functions

I receive the following error:

```
1> resistor.cpp(7): error C2084: function 'Resistor::Resistor(int,std::string,double,int [])' already has a body
1>          resistor.h(25) : see previous definition of '{ctor}'
```

With every single one of my class functions, even though in resistor.h I have don't have any empty implementations:

Resistor.h:

```
class Resistor
{
private:
   int rIndex;
   double resistance; // resistance (in Ohms)
   string name; // C++ string holding the label
   int endpointNodeIDs[2]; // IDs of nodes it attaches to

public:    
   Resistor(int rIndex_,string name_,double resistance_,int endpoints_[2]);

}
```

Resistor.cpp:

```
Resistor::Resistor(int rIndex_,string name_,double resistance_,int endpoints_[2])
{
    if (nodeArray[endpoints_[0]].addResistor(rIndex_) && NodeArray[endpoints_[1]].addResistor(rIndex_))
{
    rIndex = rIndex_;
    name = name_;
    resistance = resistance_;
    endpointNodeIDs[0] = endpoints_[0];
    endpointNodeIDs[1] = endpoints_[1];
}

return;
}
```

etc. for each of my class functions

Can anybody help me?

p.s. I also receive the following error, once again for every function in resistor class (except for the constructor, mysteriously):

```
1>rparser.cpp(301): error C2264: 'Resistor::setIndex' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called
```

Comment: And is the constructor shown in `resistor.h` on line 25? If not, then please show line 25 of `resistor.h`.

Comment: Yes, line 25 of resistor.h is
    Resistor(int rIndex_,string name_,double resistance_,int endpoints_[2]);

Comment: And you are 100% sure that the semicolon is actually there after the constructor declaration in the header file? You don't have any other error messages? If so please show them as well.

Comment: Missing brace at the end of the `Resistor` class declaration would be my guess.

Comment: Joachim: I just have an instance of that error for every function in my resistor class. I have another error that also appears for every function (except for the constructor) in resistor too (I'll post it in the question).
John: I didn't paste the entire class in, but I'll add that in the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: And you terminate the class definition with a semicolon? I.e. `class Resistor { ... };`

Comment: Are you including resistor.cpp in resistor.h by any chance? Don't do that. In fact, do not include cpp files anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is missing `;` at the end of `Resistor` class declaration (not its constructor).

It should be `};` instead of `}`. Regards.